# Trying to Solve the mystery of few experiments on event loop of node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

Here after making some small functional components, I have continued some tests on event loop.
Need Help for experiment NO -1 2 & 3 and want to know how they output of those has come.

**Learned Event Loop from this playlist:**
[Playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L18RHG2DwwA&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwj1_l8acs_lBi3a0HNb3bAN)

**Reference Image, I followed**
[image: Eventloop.jpg]

**Library I made for conducting experiments**

```
//functional programmed library for testing eventloop.
import { readFile, createReadStream } from "fs";

type callback = () => void;

function logger(txt: string) {
  console.log(txt);
}

function sleep(time?: number) {
  const start = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - start < (time ? time : 500)) {
    continue;
  }
  console.log("wake up! ⏰");
}

function io(cb: callback): void {
  readFile(__filename, cb);
};

function tick(cb: callback): void {
  process.nextTick(cb);
}

function promise(cb: callback): void {
  Promise.resolve().then(cb);
}

function close(cb: callback): void {
  const stream = createReadStream(__filename);
  stream.close();
  stream.on("close", cb);
}

function timeout(cb: callback): void {
  setTimeout(cb, 0);
}

function checker(cb: callback): void {
  setImmediate(cb);
}

function bounce(set: Set<string>, source: string): () => void {
  return () => {
    console.log(`______${source}_______`);
    if (set.has("checker")) checker(() => { logger("checker"); });
    if (set.has("timeout")) timeout(() => { logger("timeout"); });
    if (set.has("close")) close(() => { logger("close"); });
    if (set.has("tick")) tick(() => { logger("tick"); });
    if (set.has("promise")) promise(() => { logger("promise"); });
    if (set.has("io")) io(() => { logger("io"); });
    sleep(1000);
  };
}
```

**DISCLAIMER:** All below experiment are conducted as single unit and ensured that all callbacks are pushed before starting of eventloop by blocking the callstack for 1sec using sleep function.

**Experiment-0: Showcasing the order that I expect on other experiments**

```
io(bounce(new Set(["checker", "close"]), "io"));
timeout(() => logger("timeout"));
tick(() => logger("tick"));
promise(() => logger("promise"));
```

**Output of Exp0:**

```
tick
promise
timeout
io
checker
close
```

**Experiment 1:**

```
io(bounce(new Set(["checker", "close", "timeout"]), "io"));
```

**Expected Output:**

```
______io_______
checker
close
timeout
```

**Real Output:**

```
______io_______
checker
timeout
close
```

**Experiment 2:**

```
close(bounce(new Set(["timeout", "checker", "io"]), "close"));
```

**Expected Output:**

```
______close_______
timeout
checker
io
```

**Real Output:**

```
______close_______
checker
timeout
io
```

**Experiment 3:**

```
checker(bounce(new Set(["close", "io", "timeout"]), "checker"));
```

**Expected Output:**

```
______checker_______
close
timeout
io
```

**Real Output:**

```
______checker_______
timeout
close
io
```

I am just expecting clarification of my experiments that why they don't have the Expected output I wanted for experiments 1,2 & 3. Because as per the teaching of that playlist and the reference image node JS should have printed my expected output.

Comment: Not sure where you got that "reference image" from. The only reference is https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick

Comment: if I follow that reference image also you can see that in experiment 1 my polling phase (io) has a callback function which triggers one checker event, one close event and one timer event. So according to node documentation also I should get checker-> close->timer. But the thing I am getting is checker->timer->close. I hope you would understand now that my image also represents the same exact thing.

Comment: I have the same confusion. There may be something wrong with that playlist video.

Answer (score 1):

So, as shown in the [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick) and in your reference video, the order of execution is: 
**timer -> IO callbacks -> IO polling -> check -> close callbacks** 
right?

The problem here is that,

```
const stream = createReadStream(__filename);
stream.close();
stream.on("close", cb);
```

This is not adding to your close queue; it's actually doing IO polling.

So let me explain your first experiment:
you have put checker,close, and timeout in the IO callback.

1. When the IO callback completes, two callbacks will be added: one checker and one timeout. However, as I said, close is actually IO polling. (prints: ______ io______ )
2. IO polling for a readable stream and adds a callback to the IO queue.
3. checker callbacks execute    (prints: checker)
4. No callbacks in the close queue; move to timer
5. timer callback executes (prints: timeout)
6. loop continues, and now one IO callback (from step 2) will be executed (prints: close).

Now, in the same way, you can check other experiments as well. 
I hope this will help you.